# Haskell print statement

Tags: haskell, printing

I am writing in Haskell and want to print a statement in a function and also call another function and I dont know why this isn't working. Could someone possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong or provide a more logical solution?

My error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `IO ()'
In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "Missing closing bracket"
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn "Missing closing bracket";
       evaluate_input }
```

The code:

```
    bracket_content [] 0 = []
bracket_content (first:rest) counter 
    | is_open_bracket first  = first : bracket_content rest (counter + 1)
    | is_close_bracket first = first : bracket_content rest (counter - 1)
    | counter == 0 = []
    | otherwise = first : bracket_content rest counter
bracket_content _ _ = do putStrLn "Missing closing bracket" --error here
                         evaluate_input

evaluate_input :: IO ()
evaluate_input = do
  putStrLn "Enter Expression or 'q' to exit calculator: "
  expression <- getLine
  case expression of
    a:as -> return a
  unless (expression == ['q']) $ evaluate_expression expression
 where evaluate_expression e  = do 
                                   putStrLn . show $ calculate e 
                                   evaluate_input
```

Comment: You're leaving out crucial information. What's the error? What are the type of the functions?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear I edited my post above. Basically I just want the error message to print and then call evaluate_input.

Comment: All of the code snippets from the error seem to work fine, you need to include more code.

Comment: Again my apologies I changed the above code again sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to make `bracket_content` return two different types. The first two patterns return lists, while the last pattern returns an `IO ()`.  The compile error  is indicating that GHC inferred (because you use cons (`:`) on the recursive call) or read from your type signature the type of `bracket_content` to be

```
bracket_content :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
```

but your last pattern returns an `IO ()`. I think you might be trying to return a list of characters that you can later print: you are appending an open bracket to whatever the recursive call returns.

One potential solution is to make every pattern return an `IO ()`:

```
bracket_content _ 0 = return ()
bracket_content (first:rest) counter
    | is_open_bracket first = do putChar first
                                 bracket_content rest (counter + 1)
    | is_close_bracket first = do putChar first
                                  bracket_content rest (counter - 1)
    | otherwise = do putChar first
                     bracket_content rest counter
bracket_content _ _ = do putStrLn "Missing closing bracket"
                         evaluate_input
```

I'm not sure if this will accomplish what you want, but at least it compiles. The difference between your version and my version is that in my version, every pattern returns an IO (), giving your function the signature:

```
bracket_content :: [Char] -> Int -> IO ()
```

Also notice that I removed your guard

```
| counter == 0 = []
```

because I added it to the first pattern, which now prints nothing if the counter is 0, regardless of if the list is empty or not.

Comment: All I want is to call baracket_content and have it print a statement and call another function. I am just confused on how I would define it?

Comment: @user2106089: I would just like to point out that if what you want to do is error handling, its usually more "haskell style" to return an option type like Maybe or Either and to the actual "error handling" and printing stuff outside the bracket function.